# Install VMware Fusion 5 from ISO image on my Mac

Tags: virtualization, iso

I have an ISO image of VMware Fusion 5 that I would like to install from on my iMac.  How can I do it? I know I can install from a .dmg file and I now I can install from an ISO image when I already have a virtual machine installed, but can I install the real Applications from an ISO image?

Comment: As far as I know, VMware Fusion is distributed as a .dmg file. Are you sure you got the format right?

Comment: @patrix, VMware distributed VMware Fusion on CD and electronic downloads through version 5 and only electronic download starting with version 6.

Comment: Doesn't the ISO get mounted when you double-click it (check the Finder sidebar)?

Comment: If it's a legitimate ISO image of a VMware Fusion install CD simply double-click it to mount it in Finder and then double-click VMware Fusion icon to launch the Installation Assistant. Then follow the instructions in the Assistant to install VMware Fusion. At the end of the installation, the Assistant prompts for your serial number.  If you don't have a legitimate  VMware Fusion 5 serial number you'll not be able to purchase one for that version, nor can you get downgrade rights for a version 5 serial number when purchasing a  current version license as version 5 is no longer supported.

Comment: @user3439894 Which OS ? VMware fusion 5 is not compatible with newer OSX 10.11

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like, Have a look at: [Supported host operating systems for VMware Fusion and VMware Fusion Pro (2088571)](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2088571)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the Mac will treat an .ISO file the same as a .DMG file, at least in my experience...

So put the file on your Mac and double click on it and see what happens.

Failing that rename it to .DMG and try again.

It is quite possible that the .ISO file you have is the Windows version and has only the Windows installers on it (Setup.exe or Install.msi, etc.) but as counter intuitive these suggestions sound, they have worked for me and should at least allow you to open the .ISO and see what lies within.

And a commenter reminds me that there is no VMWare *Fusion* for the PC, rather it is called VMWare *Workstation.*

Comment: There is no Windows version of VMware Fusion.